# Updating A table using an inner join, count and date variable in the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update a table with information based on another.

I have a response table from clients indicating whether they accomplished a request with a boolean varchar of 'Y or N'.

Because I want to aggregately sum the amount of responses and see the percentage of replies and track them on a weekly basis I developed the following query.

```
declare @week1S DATE
set @week1S = '07/01/2016'
declare @week1E DATE
set @week1E = ' 07/07/2016'
Update ArbitrageResponse
Set b.arbcount_1 = COUNT(a.ARB_accomplished)
from arbimport as a
Inner Join ArbitrageResponse as b
WHERE a.Requested_date>=@week1S and a.Requested_date<=@week1E
Group by a.dispatch_group_name
```

I am getting an error on the where clause?

Comment: If you want to be a programmer, you need to unlearn your error-blindness. **Read** the error. Try to understand it. If you need to ask for help, **the text of the error is important**.

Comment: Also, pick an RDBMS. Is it `mysql` or `sql-server`? Do not just add random tags to "get more people looking at it".

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Feel free to add back the tag(s) for the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem started when you tried to use `INNER JOIN` without `ON` clause.
Try following statement:

```
declare @week1S DATE = '07/01/2016';
declare @week1E DATE = ' 07/07/2016';
WITH A as (
    SELECT COUNT(ARB_accomplished) as ARB_accomplished_CNT 
    FROM arbimport
    WHERE Requested_date>=@week1S and Requested_date<=@week1E
    GROUP BY dispatch_group_name
    )
Update ArbitrageResponse
Set arbcount_1 = (SELECT ARB_accomplished_CNT FROM A)
```

However, it might not give you result you need, but at least it gives you an idea.